# Identify the w3wp System.Diagnostics.Process for a given application pool

Tags: iis, application-pool, system.diagnostics, w3wp

I got few web sites running on my server.

I have a "diagnostic" page in an application that shows the **amount of memory** for the current process (very useful).

Now this app is 'linked' to another app, and I want my diagnostic page to be able to display the amot of memory for another w3wp process.

To get the amount of memory, I use a simple code :

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("w3wp");
string memory = this.ToMemoryString(process.WorkingSet64);
```

How can I identify my second w3wp process, knowing its application pool ?

I found a corresponding thread, but no appropriate answer :
[Reliable way to see process-specific perf statistics on an IIS6 app pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372080/reliable-way-to-see-process-specific-perf-statistics-on-an-iis6-app-pool)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher.aspx) to identify to which application pool a given `w3wp.exe` process belongs:

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\YOURSERVER\root\cimv2");
var query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where Name = 'w3wp.exe'");
using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
{
    foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
    {
        var commandLine = process["CommandLine"].ToString();
        var pid = process["ProcessId"].ToString();
        // This will print the command line which will look something like that:
        // c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -a \\.\pipe\iisipm49f1522c-f73a-4375-9236-0d63fb4ecfce -t 20 -ap "NAME_OF_THE_APP_POOL"
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", pid, commandLine);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also get the PID using the IIS ServerManager component; way, if you need to access it in code, without redirecting and parsing console output;

```
public static int GetIISProcessID(string appPoolName)
{
    Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager serverManager = new   
        Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager();
    foreach (WorkerProcess workerProcess in serverManager.WorkerProcesses)
    {
        if (workerProcess.AppPoolName.Equals(appPoolName))
            return workerProcess.ProcessId;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's the way!