# Is it possible that filter IIS worker processes with more criteria?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, envdte, visual-studio-automation

I have a small block of code like below for listing all IIS worker process. (w3wp.exe)

But I need more filtering criteria when multiple `w3wp.exe` processes exist. Is there any option for filter with Application Pool Name or Site Name?

```
var processes = ((DTE2)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0"))
                              .Debugger
                              .LocalProcesses
                              .Cast<EnvDTE.Process>()                                      
                              .Where(proc => proc.Name.Contains("w3wp.exe"));

if (!processes.Any())
{
    Debug.WriteLine("no w3wp");
}
else if (processes.Count() > 1)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("multiple w3wp");      
    var p = processes.Where(x => ???).Single();
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("single w3wp");
}
```

System Info

- IIS 10
- Visual Studio 2017
- .Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identify the w3wp System.Diagnostics.Process for a given application pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160726/identify-the-w3wp-system-diagnostics-process-for-a-given-application-pool).  BTW it's not necessary to use VS Automation just to list local processes

Comment: Thanks for info @MickyD. I will attach the process after finding the process. So VS Automation required.

Comment: Ah yes good point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shared my solution for those who will need it in the future.

Find the ProcessId you are looking for.

```
using System.Management;

public int GetProcessId()
{
  using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process where Name = 'w3wp.exe'"))
  {
    foreach (ManagementObject process in searcher.Get())
    {
      if (process["CommandLine"].ToString().Contains("**YOUR-SEARCH-CRITERIA**"))
      return Convert.ToInt32(process["ProcessId"].ToString());
    }
  }

 throw new Exception("Not found.");
}
```

Than attach with the ProcessId.

```
var process = ((DTE2)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.15.0"))
                            .Debugger
                            .LocalProcesses
                            .Cast<EnvDTE.Process>()                                      
                            .Where(proc => proc.ProcessID == GetProcessId())
                            .FirstOrDefault();
if(process != null)
   process.Attach();
```